Powershell Domain Join with encrypted password
i build a powershell script to automate our client installations.
Part of that is the domain join.
We are diving into Admin Tiering and wanted to seperate the right to join a client to a specific service account.
Now i want to adjust my script (which used domain admins creds to join a client) by adding the creds of the service account, so that there should be no input nessesary.
The Script runs from a usb stick and i dont want the password to stand in plaintext inside the ps1 file. Maybe the Stick gets lots or something like this.
Do you have any solutions?
The following solution doesnt work.
# Convert the plain-text password to a SecureString
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "YourPlainTextPasswordHere" -AsPlainText -Force

# Convert the SecureString to an encrypted string and store it
$EncryptedPassword = $SecurePassword | ConvertFrom-SecureString

# Output the encrypted password (copy this for use in the script)
$EncryptedPassword

# Set the domain, service account credentials, and computer name
$domain = "yourdomain.local"
$serviceAccount = "domain\serviceAccount"
$computerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME

# Encrypted password string (this is the string you copied earlier)
$encryptedPassword = "YourEncryptedPasswordHere"

# Decrypt the password
$securePassword = $encryptedPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString

# Create a PSCredential object with the service account and the decrypted password
$credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($serviceAccount, $securePassword)

# Join the domain
Add-Computer -DomainName $domain -Credential $credential -Restart -Force

Write-Host "Computer successfully joined the domain and will restart now."


I think your issue is that the SecureString is, by design, tied to the machine that you encrypt it on, so trying to decrypt/use it on another machine won't work.  Have a look here, for more info: Powershell Secure password to work on any machine, though I don't think there is a really secure method of doing what you want to do - the user is always going to have to have some way to decrypt the password to use it.

Thank you, you confirm my suspicion that it won't be so easy... Would it perhaps be possible for the user to reach a network share that does not require the client to belong to the domain? So that the password is then available in a share for just this one user and can be retrieved when the script is executed?

I quess you want to do a DirectAccess Offline Domain Join (and prevent scripts that handle passwords).
